# Wordpress: Make plugin option to modify jquery

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am trying to add plugin option to update jquery but don't have any idea how to do that. I am adding jquery using wp_enqueue_script() and so it is not allowing to add php function ( get_option() ) to the jquery code. Please help me to resolve this.

Jquery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    $cnt = 0;

    jQuery('#add-photo-button').click(function(){

    if($cnt == 3){ // where 3 should replaced with plugin option function/varible
        jQuery('#add-photo-button').prop('disabled', true);
        jQuery('#add-photo-button').addClass('disabled');
    }
    $cnt++;
        var current_count = jQuery('input[type="file"]').length;
        //var next_count = current_count + 1;

        jQuery('#file-upload').prepend('<p><input type="file" name="photo[]" /></p>');    

    });  

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the [wp_localize_script()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) function.

You must enqueue your script, then localize (or rather: pass the data as inline JavaScript) the data you want to reference in the JavaScript and lastly update your script to reference the newly localized global object. Please see my example below.

---

### Example

1- Enqueue your script in your plugin, then "localize" the variable data using `wp_localize_script()`. Make sure you use the same handle for both function calls.

```
<?php

// !! Edit the variables below to suit your plugin

$add_photo_button_handle = 'some_handle';
$add_photo_button_js = plugins_url( '/add_photo_button.js', __FILE__ );

$photo_num = get_option( 'add_photo_button_cnt' ); // Here you fetch the option data.

// Enqueue your script
wp_enqueue_script( $add_photo_button_handle, $add_photo_button_js );

// Set the data you want to pass to your script here
$data = array( 'photo_button_cnt' => $photo_num );

// Localize the script, the 'photo_button_cnt' value will now be accessible as a property in the global 'add_photo_button' object.
wp_localize_script( $add_photo_button_handle, 'add_photo_button', $data );
?>
```

2- Change your script to reference the localized object

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    $cnt = 0;

    jQuery('#add-photo-button').click(function(){

    //============================================
    // See how we access the localized object.
    //============================================

    if($cnt == add_photo_button.photo_button_cnt ){ 
        jQuery('#add-photo-button').prop('disabled', true);
        jQuery('#add-photo-button').addClass('disabled');
    }
    $cnt++;
        var current_count = jQuery('input[type="file"]').length;
        //var next_count = current_count + 1;

        jQuery('#file-upload').prepend('<p><input type="file" name="photo[]" /></p>');    

    });  
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried this but as I never used this function so no idea how to use it. Can you please give me some example to use it. I would appreciate that.

Comment: @pixelngrain Sorry for the late response, I've updated my answer now.

Comment: Wonderful! let me try and get back to you.

Comment: I have try this code. There is an issue that the javascript not getting value of the option and it is rendering directly this `if($cnt == add_photo_button.photo_button_cnt )` but not `if($cnt == 3 )` or so and resulting button not adding any input field. Any idea?

Comment: Amazing! its working now. There was an issue in wp_enqueue_script. I haven't defined dependency of jquery. Thanks a lot